# Chinese words that are their own antonyms

Tags: etymology, antonyms

Are there (m)any Chinese words that are their own antonyms? Similar to English "terrific", "wicked", etc. (which originally had negative meanings and now have positive meanings).

I imagine that as Chinese words are so heavily tied to their etymology (and the meaning of the characters used to write them), "auto-antonyms" would be rare???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's sometimes refered to in the traditional scholarship as '[反训](http://www.zdic.net/cd/ci/4/ZdicE5Zdic8FZdic8D26589.htm).' 钱锺书 has an extensive discussion of it in his 《管锥编·周易正义·论易之三名》.

Comment: Nice to know there's a term for it. There is a bit about it here http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AE%AD%E8%AF%82%E5%AD%A6

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're asking, but 厉害 (li4hai) can have both a good or bad meaning depending on the context. For example, if a student says a teacher is li4hai they probably mean strict. If you do something and demonstrate great ability, someone might say, "Wow! You're really li4hai!"

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are a lot, very often it depends on the context and how you say it (like the tone).

For example: 讨厌 means dislike, but can mean like some times, such as in: 真是个小讨厌 (used wen describing my little noisy baby but means I really like my baby, not dislike).